# LUKS error after unlocking waiting for cleartext object

Tags: mount, encryption, external-hdd, luks

I have a an external hardrive which is encrypted with LUKS. It was working fine for a while but now when I try to unlock it I get

```
$ udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdb1 
Passphrase: 
Error unlocking /dev/sdb1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error waiting for cleartext object after unlocking /dev/sdb1Timed out waiting for object
```

I get the same error when I try to mount it trough nautilus which is the way I usually unlock it.